# I want to upload textfile into mysql

Tags: node.js, file, express, text, file-upload

I want the user to type in the ACE text editor then I want to store this text in a file in the MySQL database. How can I do it?
I am a beginner in Node.js and using express.
I am getting an error while connecting to the MySQL

> { Error: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by
>   server; consider upgrading MySQL client
>       at PromisePool.query (F:\projects\Project1\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:322:22)
>       at Object. (F:\projects\Project1\app.js:13:4)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:608:3   message: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL
>   client',   code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',   errno: 1251,
>   sqlState: '08004',   sqlMessage: 'Client does not support
>   authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL
>   client' }

Comment: Which part of this task is causing you a problem?

Comment: I don't know how can I upload a file into MySQL using node

Comment: How can send the text to the server which method would be best? I think there are two options first is in the hidden field and another is by ajax request Which one do you think is the best .

Comment: These two methods can work, there is not much difference, the best is the one you prefer. Maybe try one and see if it works for you. If not, update your question with the problematic code.

Comment: how can I convert above code in the code which uses promises?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question. You can ask another one instead.

Comment: that previous problem is solved I have uploaded file in MySQL but currently, I get an error here so I changed the question

Comment: Please ask another one so someone with same problem can find something helpful here in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using mysql server version 8, which has default auth mode not currently supported by mysql or mysql2 (both libraries have some work in progress to add this, see https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/pull/1962 for more details ). One way to work around this is to change auth plugin for your user is to execute following sql from your favourite client

```
update user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='your user name'; 
flush privileges;
```